# Python: Creating a Set with Xor-like behavior

Tags: python, set

I have a use-case for an efficient implementation of a Set with XOR-like behaviour.

A set that, if an element is added, *removes* the element from the set if it is already contained in the set, but adds it in case it is not. See the below code:

```
# Create set `a`
a = xorset((0,0,0,1,1,2))
assert a == {0,2}
a.add(0)
assert a == {2}
a.add(0)
assert a == {0,2}

a.update((0,0))
assert a == {0,2}
a.update((0,0,0,2,1))
assert a == {1}
```

My best attempt so far has been to use the `collections` Counter object to create sets like so:

```py
from collections import Counter
def xorset(it):
    return set(k for k,v in Counter(it) if v % 2 == 1)
```

and then to manually implement the add & update operations:

```py
import itertools
def xorset_add(s,e):
    if e in s:
         s.remove(e)
    else:
         s.add(e)
    return s # not necessary as works in place
def xorset_update(s,it):
    return set(k for k,v in Counter(itertools.chain(s,it)) if v % 2 == 1)
```

I would imagine there'd be significant speed-ups possible if there was a lib that handled the addition/removal of new elements, but I have not been able to find any. Does anyone know of the existence of one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I've misunderstood you, it sounds like the `set` method `symmetric_difference_update` does what you're looking for, and as it's a built-in, it's about as fast as you're going to get.

```
>>> s = set((1,2,3))
>>> s
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s.symmetric_difference_update(set((2,)))         ["add" 2, but removes 2]
>>> s
{1, 3}
>>> s.symmetric_difference_update(set((2,)))         ["add" 2 back]
>>> s
{1, 2, 3}
>>> s.symmetric_difference_update(set((3,4)))        ["add" 3 and 4, but removes 3]
>>> s
{1, 4}
```

You can perform the same operation with the `^=` operator:

```
>>> s
{1, 4}
>>> s ^= set((4,))
>>> s
{1}
>>> s ^= set((4,))
>>> s
{1, 4}
```

**Update**: implementation of `xorset` class provided by @Erwin Haasnoot

A full immutable xorset implementation, subclassing frozenset, will look like below:

````py
import itertools
from collections import Counter

class xorset(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, it=()):
        it = (k for k, v in Counter(it).items() if v & 1)
        return super().__new__(cls, it)

    def add(self, v):
        return self ^ {v}

    def update(self, it):
        return self.__class__(itertools.chain(self, it))```
````

Comment: Interesting! I played around with it a bit, and it does seem to do what I need if my input is a set, so this will be good to use! Unfortunately, for the generic Iterable case, first converting to a set will not quite do what I need:
```python
a = set((0,0,1))```
 will result in ```a == {0,1}```, whereas I want elements that appear an even amount of time to be extinguished, leaving a set with just `1`: ```a == {1}```. This will work well for the `add` case though!

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Well, I suppose what you could do is define a ```xorset``` class that inherits ```set``` and redefine the ```add``` and ```update``` methods to remove doubles before passing what's left to ```super()``` and make use of built-in symmetric difference for everything else.

Comment: That is a good idea. I will update your answer with some sample code I wrote and accept it. Giving you the answering kudos. 

Still wanting a better solution though, that does not make such extensive use of Counter.